Are there specific name forms for Interlingua?
While it is not uncommon for Esperanto speakers to use Esperantised name forms like Ludoviko, the Interlingua community usually uses the native spelling of personal names. But I want to know, if there are name forms specific to Interlingua (maybe to be found in literary works originally written in Interlingua). Some examples of such names (with quotations where they are sourced from, if possible) are welcome.

A category I completely overlooked while asking the question are monarchs, their names were once customly translated between the European languages. Taking the Interlingua Wikipedia as a measuring stick, the treatment of their names is somewhat inconsistent and I note the following

There are Interlingua names for the Ancient Roman imperators, like Cesare Augusto, Claudio, Constantino, or Juliano ( https://ia.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Imperatores_roman )
For British monarchs, several of them are in Interlingua: Anna, Carolo III, Eduardo, Georgio, Guilielmo, Maria, Ricardo; but: Elisabeth. Victoria is undecidable ( https://ia.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Monarchas_britannic )
Swedish kings go by their usual names without modification ( https://ia.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categoria:Reges_de_Svedia )
Others are inconsistent, I find Carolo Magne (Charlemagne) and Ludovico V besides Charles Martell and Napoléon III.

